# Equal column using flex

Tags: html, css, gridview, flexbox, grid

I have created pure css accordion for mobile and grid view for web.
now i'm facing issue with column width for web view. in current implementation column width is not same for all column.
I want to create an equal column using flex.

Note: this html is responsive for mobile there will be accordion for mobile and for web there will be row.

```css
/*
 CSS for the main interaction
*/
.accordion > input[name="collapse"] {
  display: none;

  /*position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;*/
}

/* .accordion label,
.accordion .content{
 max-width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 } */

.accordion .content {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 0;

  padding: 10px 0;
}

.accordion > input[name="collapse"]:checked ~ .content {
  height: 200px;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
}

.edit-delete .item {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.edit-delete a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
/* For Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
  .accordion > input[name="collapse"]:checked ~ .content {
    height: auto;
  }
  .accordion .handle {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .handle label,
  .content,
  .col,
  .item {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.accordion {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.accordion > input[name="collapse"]:checked ~ .content {
  border-top: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion .handle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 0;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* .accordion label:hover,
.accordion label:focus {
  background: #252525;
} */

.accordion .handle label:before {
  content: "";
  border: solid #008080;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
.handle label:before {
  display: none;
}
.accordion > input[name="collapse"]:checked ~ .handle label:before {
  content: "";
  border: solid #008080;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.accordion p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* .container{
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} */

.handle label,
.content,
.col {
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .content {
    display: block;
  }
  .content .col {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .accordion {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
  }
  .accordion .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .accordion label {
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .handle label:before {
    display: block;
  }
  .edit-delete {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .accordion .handle {
    height: 100px;
  }
  .handle .item {
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .accordion > input[name="collapse"]:checked ~ .handle {
    height: auto;
  }
  .item {
    width: auto;
  }
  .item span:first-child {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .edit-delete a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTML Expand Collapse Text Example</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Codeconvey" />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <!-- Accordion CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="accordion">
      <input type="radio" name="collapse" id="handle1" />
      <div class="handle">
        <label for="handle1">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>xyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Gender</span>
            <span>Male</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Dealership</span>
            <span>fsdfsd</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Branch</span>
            <span>sdfsd</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>User Type</span>
            <span>Sales Executive</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Status</span>
            <span>Active</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col edit-delete">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Edit</a>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="accordion">
      <input type="radio" name="collapse" id="handle2" />
      <div class="handle">
        <label for="handle2">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>Zyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>xyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>xyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col edit-delete">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Edit</a>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="accordion">
      <input type="radio" name="collapse" id="handle3" />
      <div class="handle">
        <label for="handle3">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>xyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>xyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1234567890</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Name</span>
            <span>xyz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>12345625320</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item">
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <span>1212121212</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col edit-delete">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Edit</a>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please check on fullscreen view

please see screenshot below for inconsistency column width
[image]

Comment: Your posted code has identical column widths because all of the rows have identical data ("Raman Rajan"). Please update your HTML to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dai i have updated the html thank you :)

Comment: I see the updated data, but the grid still renders perfectly for me.

Comment: @dai issue is on web view above 1023px please check on fullscreen. for mobile there is no issue. column width should be equal for all columns.

Comment: Yes, when I view it in full-screen at 1920px wide it looks fine, it also looks fine at 1024px and 1000px, and 400px. **Please post a screenshot how it looks for you.**

Comment: @Dai added screenshot..all column should be equal size

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to use `display: grid;` instead of `display: flex;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved 3 steps:

1. set `display: contents` on `.handle, .handle > label, .content, .col` elements. This will make all `.item` elements children of  `section.accordion`
2. For all `.item` elements set `width: 0` and `flex-grow: 1` this will makes all columns to have the same width.
3. adjust padding on `section.accordion` to match your first design.

Of course those have to be done for the web view only.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. it's working as expected thanks a lot :)